# Crystal Report Parameters in Sessions are lost

Tags: crystal-reports

I can't display my Crystal Report using parameters in Sessions. Here is my code:

```
    Sub ShowRept()
    Dim cryInv As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    cryInv.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports/SupplierSalesReport.rpt"), CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)

cryInv.SetParameterValue("@SupplierID", Session("SupplierID"))
cryInv.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", Session("StartDate"))
cryInv.SetParameterValue("@EndDate", Session("EndDate"))

CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = cryInv
' CrystalReportViewer.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

If I hard code the parameter like this:

```
 cryInv.SetParameterValue("@SupplierID", 25)
 cryInv.SetParameterValue("@StartDate", "25/10/2017")
 cryInv.SetParameterValue("@EndDate", "25/12/2017")`
```

then the report shows properly.

How to solve the problem?

Regards,

Comment: Have you checked if Session holds the value of "SupplierId" etc? As this  should not happen. Also check if it has correct datatype etc.

Comment: Hi you are right the session name should be Session("Supplier") instead of Session ("SupplierID").